# .Htaccess help new file on server?

Tags: http, .htaccess

Hi what does this code do, I have a seo company doing some work on my site, and just noticed this being on my server. thanks

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]

rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If users try to access `http://mydomain.com/` they will be redirected to `http://www.mydomain.com/`.

This is useful to avoid `Duplicate Content`, which search engines don't like. So it's basic SEO.

Duplicate Content means that the Content of a website is accessible at more than one URL, in your case `http://mydomain.com/` and `http://www.mydomain.com/`. The RewriteRule kills the URL without `www`.